# I made this bag from/of my old jeans

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> 1. Wine is made *from* grapes.
> 2. That bridge is made *of* steel.

A Korean dictionary says that 1’s ‘*from*’ is used because of the change of the property from grapes to wine, and there is not the change in 2 they use ‘of.' But is it really right?  I have these cases below from Webster’s Learner’s and COCA.

> a doll made *from* cloth  ([Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/from))
>   The outsole is made *from* rubber originally designed to prevent chefs from falling on greasy kitchen floors.  (COCA)

I think from the cases that ‘*from*’ are used for both cases in property change and not. This is my question: In the following sentence, “I made this bag **from** my old jeans”, can you use ‘*from*’ or '*of*'? Or do you use only ‘*of*’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In:
>
> > *I made this bag from my old jeans*
>
> can you use ‘from’ or 'of'? Or do you use only ‘of’?

Tricky question! (Anyone who thinks ELL questions are "easy" should try to explain this!)

I think it's okay to say:

> *This bag is made **of** old jeans*

and it's okay to say:

> *I made this bag **from** my old jeans*

but not:

> **I made this bag of my old jeans*

---

> A Korean dictionary says that ‘from’ is used because of the change of the property from grapes to wine, and there is not the change in 2, so they use ‘of.' But is it really right?

Prepositions are too versitile to apply a simply "rule" like that in all cases. There are too many factors at play.

Here's an example where both prepositions work fine:

> *[Hash](http://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Food/Stir-It-Up/2013/0317/Beef-pot-roast-and-potato-hash) is made **from** beef and potatoes*
>
> *[Hash](http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/traditional_roast_beef_hash/) is made **of** beef and potatoes*

When using *from*, there seems to be a slight emphasis on transformation: the beef and potatoes are turned into hash. However, when using *of*, the sentence seems to emphasize hash's basic ingredients.

Either of those sentences is fine. However, if we change how we use *made* in this sentence, only one of them seems correct:

> *I made some hash **from** beef and potatoes*    (sounds fine)
>
> *I made some hash **of** beef and potatoes*    (sounds awkward)

Why does *from* work in this sentence, but *of* doesn't? Because the sentence doesn't merely talk about the transformation of the meat and potatoes – it also emphasizes the cook's role in that transformation. So I won't deny there is a link between *from* and the concept of "transformation."

However, there's at least one other prepostion that could be used:

> *I made some hash **with** beef and potatoes*    (sounds fine)

and you can say this without a prepostion, too:

> *I made some hash **using** beef and potatoes*    (sounds okay)

Comment: I find *I made this bag of my old jeans* fine, if not the most common way to say it. To me *of* can carry the same genitival meaning as *from.*

Answer (score 4):

No, "of" would not work with "I made this bag *of my old jeans."  It would be "from my old jeans" or "out of my old jeans".

I made this hat out of an old bucket. *Très chic*, no?

I made this vest out of a shirt I had. One of the sleeves was stained, so I took the sleeves off, and hemmed it.

I made this bag from some fabric I had left over.

I made this bag from some left-over fabric.

Comment: You made a believer out of me :) @TRo

Comment: Project Runway, watch out.

Comment: I find *I made this bag of my old jeans* fine. It can carry the same genitival meaning as *from.*