# How is "made FROM virgin [any material]" possible? Shouldn't it be "made OF virgin"?

Tags: word-usage, figurative-language

What I know about ['made from' and 'made of'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/made-of-vs-made-from) is this:

> Chairs are made of wood - the wood is still wood, you see that ***AND*** 
>  Paper is made from wood -wood disappears, you don't see wood

What I know about the word [*virgin* as an adjective](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/virgin_2) is this:

> *in its original pure or natural condition and **not changed,** touched or spoiled*

So, keeping in mind that if ***the original material is changed, it does not remain virgin**. Said that, --[anything] made **FROM** virgin [anything] is not possible.

But [here...](http://www.mtu.edu/news/stories/2014/september/ethical-filament-can-fair-trade-plastic-save-people-planet.html)

> What makes it *(they are talking about 3D printer filament)* especially attractive is the cost of conventional filament ***made from virgin plastic***: about $35 to $50 a kilogram.

[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2009/feb/26/toilet-roll-america) reads:

> *Extra-soft, quilted and multi-ply toilet roll **made from virgin wood** causes more damage than gas-guzzlers, fast food or McMansions, say campaigners*

### Question

Now, if we *change/alter* the original material, how is it possible to call it *virgin?* The moment you *change/alter* the main material, it's not virgin anymore! :)

So shouldn't we use ***'made of virgin'*** (since it's not changed) over ***'made from virgin'*** which means 'altered'.

Comment: The article's use of "virgin wood" is fine. Note what is at the bottom of that article: *This article was amended on Wednesday 4 March 2009. We mistakenly referred to virgin forests when virgin wood, which includes that from planted, managed forests, was meant. This has been corrected.*

Comment: I'll give you a hint: the from/of distinction you mention at the beginning of your question is something most native speakers don't really think about, and prepositions are flexible enough that there are plenty of cases were either _from_ or _of_ will work fine, depending on the wording of the rest of sentence. I hash this out some more in my answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41312/i-made-this-bag-from-of-my-old-jeans/41364#41364). "Made from virgin olive oil" is just fine, so long as "made from olive oil" would be okay in the same context.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This sort of thing is quite confusing for non-native speakers.

Comment: I don't think we should treat language as logic. But let's take a ride along your reasoning line for a bit. You gathered a) *X is made of Y*, X is still Y; b) *X is made from Y*, X is not Y anymore (in their words, Y disappears); and c) *virgin* means "untouched, not changed, etc." From them you deduced that we should use "*made of virgin Y* (since it's not changed) over *made from virgin* which means 'altered'" [sic]. This is illogical.

Comment: Consider X when X is not virgin Y (as you said, "it's not virgin anymore"): which one would you prefer between 1) *X is made of virgin Y*, and 2) *X is made from virgin Y*? With a) and b), you should be able to answer the question. (Imho, *virgin* of *virgin Y* has nothing to do with the choice of preposition (*of* or *from*) at all.)

Comment: @J.R. just curious about this - On the [ELU site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892), the **nuance** of 'made of/from' is defined, and this is how **actually** natives' sharp eyes see what we cannot. In fact, I always take care of made of/from after learning form that excellent answer. The question came to my mind because I *learned* the real use of made from/of.

Comment: MV: What I'm saying is: those _nuances_ are just that: **nuances** (or subtleties). They might help you pick the right preposition 9 times out of 10, but they'll lead you astray if you "overapply" them (as in, "How can it still be virgin if it's been changed?"). (That said, I share the confusion of @Ben about the downvotes).

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, learning the language precisely costs me. Check out four downvotes that too for a question!

Comment: Yes, but three upvotes. It's still a net gain for your rep. :^)

Comment: @J.R. *"(That said, I share the confusion of -- about the down votes)."* <== That sounds like a good question for *ELL Meta*. Why don't you ask there?

Comment: @F.E., JR, Ben, I wonder if it's some misunderstanding about the word *virgin*? Cuz otherwise it's unfathomable to me ...

Comment: @J.R. hahaa true! :)

Comment: @Araucaria I have been following this thread as the OP's post has changed, and been watching and reading the answer posts as they were made and edited. You can tell that I've been here early on from that first comment of mine under the OP's question post. And so, I do understand why there have been so many downvotes.

Comment: @F.E. Sorry, I'm feeling dumb, why is it?

Comment: @Araucaria What "it" are you asking for?

Comment: @F.E. that there've been so many downvotes?

Comment: @Araucaria I had upvoted this [answer post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/41608/8758) in this thread, since I thought it a good answer (look at the 1st version of that answer), and then, since I was procrastinating, watched the developments, the edits and comments, etc., that went on in this thread. If you look at that answer post and comment(s), that's the tip of the iceberg. I can't speak for the other downvoters, but at the end, after an answer was "accepted", I finally had enough and had to down vote the OP. (If you want more in-depth info, then an ELL Meta thread might be appropriate.)

Comment: @Araucaria don't get into it! Many don't know the reason to downvote. To some, it's merely a *practice!* Aim at learning the language and accepting answers that seem logical to you. No matter who answers how. I've many things to say on this but I'll refrain myself doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I married a virgin" doesn't mean she's a virgin anymore. The writers chose the word **virgin** to suggest that something pure, precious, and irreplaceable is being lost—wasted on an unworthy purpose.

When the newspaper article says that the toilet paper is **made from virgin wood**, it means the state of the wood before they manufactured the toilet paper. Virgin wood is the *input* to the manufacturing process. Toilet paper is the *output.* We do not call toilet paper "wood" at all, even though that's what it's made from. From virgin wood to toilet paper—from sacred purity to filthy impurity—that's how the writers are trying to get you to see the situation.

**Made from** is more correct here, since that phrase suggests that the material was transformed when the object was made, as [wine is made from grapes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/why-is-wine-made-from-grapes-but-tables-are-made-of-wood?lq=1). **Made of** suggests that the material is still recognizable in the completed object, like a [bridge made of steel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41312). There is no exact rule, of course.

Comment: I wondered how many seconds it would take for that to get a downvote.

Comment: Thanks a ton. At least one answerer understood what I had in my mind. +1 and accepted especially for the first half of the answer.

Comment: @Ben - There oughtta be a badge for that :^) Good answer, btw.

Comment: @snailboat I hit Save after typing the first sentence, wondering if anyone would pounce on it before I finished the whole answer. Indeed that sentence alone [would be](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/would-vs-should-expressing-expectation-on-the-part-of-the-speaker) an absurd answer. Maybe the reason this question has attracted so many downvotes is also the main point of my answer: the word **virgin** has a strong emotional charge.

Comment: @J.R. Ha! Thanks. I was inspired by [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13769/6700).

Comment: @snailboat *"I see two downvotes but no explanation. Would someone care to explain either ① why the downvotes were left ..."* <== That sounds like a good question for *ELL Meta*. Why don't you ask there?

Comment: I don't have a problem with anonymous and unexplained downvotes in principle (I think they're important, in fact)—but in this case I wondered if I might learn something from asking, so I did :-) I've removed my question-comment now that Ben Kovitz has answered.

Answer (score 3):

Edit (due to changes in the OP's question):

The link J.R. supplies deals with the use of "made of" vs "made from."  And that post links to an additional post, in EL&U, which also covers the same two expressions, "made of" and "made from." I would like to throw in another possibility, "made out of," which seems to combine "made of" and "made from." (*out of* can mean *from* or *of,* depending on context).

The Guardian's usage of 'made from' is correct and idiomatic:

TP is made from virgin wood. as is
TP is made out of virgin wood.

As far as TP is made of virgin wood, I agree that some speakers may find it problematic. But not so much that it is *impossible* to say. I think *of* can be interchangeable with *from* and *out of* in such constructions. In other words, I don't think *of* necessarily carries with it the meaning that the raw material is still present in its unchanged form.

TP is made of (virgin) wood. But (virgin) wood that has been changed. The bulk of my original answer deals with why it is okay to use virgin wood in such a construction.

*of* can have more than one meaning here, basically equivalent to *from.*

*Did you know that TP is made **of** (virgin) wood?* works in my world. But then, so does

*I made this bag **of** my old jeans.* To me *of* can carry the same genitival meaning as *from* or *out of.*

Original answer (answer to an earlier version of the question):

I suggest the OP is being overly-literal and overly pedantic in his definition of *virgin wood.*

*Virgin wood* is a type of wood.

> **Virgin wood**
>   Virgin wood consists of wood and other products such as bark and sawdust which have had no chemical treatments or finishes applied.

Source: [Biomass Energy Centre](http://www.biomassenergycentre.org.uk/portal/page?_pageid=75,17300&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL).

The same site says:

> The wood processing industries, such as sawmills and timber merchants, are also a source of virgin wood in the form of offcuts, bark and sawdust.

In other words, *virgin wood* is wood from a forest that has not undergone chemical processing. This is different from other wood, which has already undergone some sort of chemical processing.

From the article:

> More than 98% of the toilet roll sold in America comes from virgin wood, said Hershkowitz. In Europe and Latin America, up to 40% of toilet paper comes from recycled products.

It seems clear that the article is opposing *virgin wood* and wood that has gone through processing. Such could be recycled wood.

If the OP does not recognize that *virgin wood* (even after being cleared from a forest, sent to the sawmill, debarked, and planked) simply means wood from a forest, as opposed to processed wood, then I do not know what else to say. In that case, it appears the OP is playing '[a subtle, specious, or crafty argument](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syllogism)' and the question is no longer one about English but about logic, specious or not.

Comment: The question is **not** about virgin wood! My comment has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

While [JR](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41606/how-is-made-from-virgin-any-material-possible-shouldnt-it-be-made-of-virg#comment78006_41606) is absolutely correct that native speakers might use either preposition in this case, I'd like to say a bit about the difference between the two, since it seems you want to get into the gritty semantic details.

> So shouldn't we use 'made of virgin' (since it's not changed) over 'made from virgin' which means 'altered'.

This is exactly why it *shouldn't* be *made of*. As you note, the definition of *virgin* is:

> in its original pure or natural condition and not changed, touched or spoiled

But here, the product in question is a toilet roll, also called toilet *paper*. Is this sort of thing made *of* wood? I and my bottom certainly hope not, because that would be very painful! During the manufacturing process, the wood is changed and made into "extra-soft, quilted and multi-ply" *paper*. Thus, it's no longer *virgin*, or even wood. *Virgin wood* in this context refers to the raw materials used to make the toilet roll, not the constituent elements of the finished product, hence *from* rather than *of*.

Answer (score 2):

In the article is not talking about the toilet roll that would be virgin. It is the raw material that used to be **virgin wood**.

So I don’t see anything wrong with the use of the **virgin wood** in the article.

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 2):

> So shouldn't we use 'made of virgin' (since it's not changed) over 'made from virgin' which means 'altered'.

No; I think you're parsing the sentence wrong. Remove the adjective *virgin*, and replace it with some other adjective:

> the cost of conventional filament made from red plastic
>
> extra-soft, quilted and multi-ply toilet roll made from fresh-cut wood

The transformations here are from wood to toilet paper, and from plastic to filament. The wood and the plastic can undergo all sorts of changes beforehand (or not) – that's outside the scope of this context.

Think of it this way:

[image]

It makes absolutely no difference what kind of wood or plastic is used – red or yellow, painted or unpainted, moldy or clean, processed or virgin – the transformation is there, and *from* is the correct preposition. In this case, the adjective has no influence on the prepostion, because we are not referring to any steps taken (or not taken) before this transformation.